# Using mock.patch.object to wrap a method on all objects of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

In some asyncio test cases, I find that I often want to wait for some method to get called, so I've written the following context manager:

```
@contextmanager
def wait_for_call(loop, obj, method, calls = 1):
    # set up some bookkeeping including a future called fut
    def cb(*args, **kwards):
        # Set fut's result to true if the right number of calls happen
    try:
        with mock.patch.object(obj, method,
                               wraps = getattr(obj, method),
                               side_effect = cb):
            yield
            loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(fut, 0.5))
    except  asyncio.futures.TimeoutError:
        raise AssertionError("Timeout waiting for call to {} of {}".format(
            method, obj)) from None
```

That works great if I'm either patching a specific instance or if I'm patching a class method.  However, there are a couple of cases where I want to patch a regular (instance) method  like this:

```
class foo:
    def bar(self): pass
x = foo()
with wait_for_call(loop, x, 'bar'): x.bar()
```

When I do that, I get a `TypeError` because  `x.bar` doesn't get `self`.  I think that's because `MagicMock` doesn't implement the descriptor protocol the same way a function does.
How can I wrap a method and get `self` to be handled correctly?

Comment: Does this work? `with wait_for_call(...) as w: w()`

Comment: @Dan  If I pass in self there it probably would, but it's not very helpful because I'm generally waiting for a call that's going to be deep in the call graph.

Answer (score 0):

In python3 functions implement the descriptor protocol and thus have a `__get__` method.

> > > def foo(self): pass
> > >           ... 
> > >       foo.**get**
> > >           
> > >       So, when a function is attached to a class as an attribute, and you try and retrieve that method from an instance of that class, the function object's `__get__` method is called.  This is how `self` is bound to the first argument.  For example, by synthesizing a call to `foo`'s `__get__` we can get a version of `foo` that appears to be a method of a string.

```
>>> a = "I am a string"
>>> foo.__get__(a,str)
<bound method foo of 'I am a string'>
```

MagicMock doesn't do this:

```
>>> m = mock.MagicMock()
>>> m.foo()
<MagicMock name='mock.foo()' id='140643153651136'>
>>> m.foo.__get__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 582, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __get__
```

It appears possible to explicitly set `__get__` on a MagicMock, but to accomplish the goal of the question there's a much simpler approach.
The `patch.object` method can be used to patch in anything, not just a `MagicMock`.  If none of the features of MagicMock are required, then you can simply patch in a new method.

```
def wait_for_call(loop, obj, method, calls = 1):
    # set up a future and call tracking
    def cb(*args, **kwargs):
        # Track number of calls and set a future when done
        return wraps(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        wraps = getattr(obj, method)
        with mock.patch.object(obj, method,
                               new= cb):
            yield
            loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(fut, 0.5))
    except  asyncio.futures.TimeoutError:
        raise AssertionError("Timeout waiting for call to {} of {}".format(
            method, obj)) from None
```

`cb` is patched into the object and since `cb` is a function, it correctly gets `self`.  This also works when an instance is patched, because the descriptor protocol is not used when an attribute is set directly on an instance.